# Quotient map on Real line

Tags: general-topology

Let $X=\Bbb R$ and $q: X \rightarrow(\Bbb R, T_{std})$ be a function

$q(x)= 
\begin{cases}
1-|x|,  & \text{x $\le1$} \\
|x-1|, & \text{x $\ge$1}
\end{cases}$

Q1 Suppose X is given the quotient topology with respect to q, can you find a simple topological space which is homeomorphic to X?

Q2 Find a subset $A\subset X$ which is connected in $T_{std}$ but disconnected in the quotient topology wrt q.

Q3 Find a subset $U\subset X$ which is open in $(X,T_{std})$ but it is not open under the quotient topology wrt q.

Quotient map is quite hard for me, in this case, I don't know how this function glues the whole $\Bbb R$. And I don't know how it looks like and I don't how to answer Q1

For Q2, I tried to use the the definition of quotient topology. Since the definition of the mapping is for $x \le1$ and x $\ge$1, so I guessed the point $x=1$ causes the disconnectedness in the quotient topology, so I picked $(\frac{1}{2},\frac{3}{2})$, which contains $1$. That interval is connected for $(\Bbb R, T_{std})$, then I split it into (\frac{1}{2},1] and $(1,\frac{3}{2})$, and I wanted to argue that both are open in the quotient topology. The latter is ok, but it seems that $q^{-1}(\frac{1}{2},1] = (-\frac{1}{2},0]\cup[0,\frac{1}{2}]\cup[1,\frac{3}{2}]$ which is not open?

For Q3, I want to use a similar approach as Q2, finding a interval contains $1$ which is open in $(X,T_{std})$ but it is not open under the quotient topology wrt q.

Can anyone help me to understand that quotient map and solve Q1-3?

Comment: It seems best to concentrate on Q1 first, as you'll need to master the definition of the quotient topology before trying the other problems. Can you state the definition of the quotient topology with respect to $q$?

Comment: @GregMartin $T_q ={V\subset X/\sim：q^{-1}(V)\in T_{std}}$ , here $X/\sim=\Bbb R$? Since $Im(q)=\Bbb R$?

Comment: @Belive: Are you sure that you have $q$ going in the right direction? As you’ve written it, the standard topology on $\Bbb R$ *is* the quotient topology generated by $q$, and you’re trying to find the source topology on $X$; unfortunately, this is not completely determined by the data. I’d have expected $q$ to have $\Bbb R$ with the standard topology as its **domain**, mapping $\Bbb R$ to $X$, and for the question to involve the quotient topology on $X$ generated by $q$.